# EF Code First - Sequence Contains more than one Element. migration creation MVC4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been building a piece of software which was intended to only have the one database (MSSQL) however this has expanded and I am now pulling customer information from a mysql database. I have been creating models that link between the two fine up until now when I am attempting to build a model that has a many to many relationship between the two. I link to the mysql database through a ADO.net Entity Datamodel called workdata.edmx
I want to have a campaign model (MSSQL) which contains a list of system  types from an exisitng mysql database. When adding the migration I receive the error "Sequence contains more than one matching element". Here are my culprit models below;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ReturnsMVC.Models;

namespace ReturnsMVC.Models
{
    public class Campaign
    {
        public Campaign()
       {
            SystemTypes = new List<system_type>();
       }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nameofcampaign { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Interaction> Interactions { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<system_type> SystemTypes { get; set; }

    }
}

using ReturnsMVC.Models;

namespace ReturnsMVC
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class system_type
    {
        public system_type()
        {
            this.customers = new HashSet<customer>();

        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<customer> customers { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Campaign> campaigns { get; set; }

    }
}
```

//model builder data
     modelBuilder.Entity()

```
           .HasMany(r => r.SystemTypes)
           .WithMany(q=>q.campaigns)
           .Map(m =>
           {
               m.ToTable("CampaignSystemTypes");
               m.MapLeftKey("campaignID");
               m.MapRightKey("systemtypeID");

           });
```

--StackTrace--

```
    PM> add-migration campaignsystemtype
Scaffolding migration 'campaignsystemtype'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.BuildCreateTableOperation(String entitySetName, String tableName, String schema, ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<FindAddedTables>b__31(XElement es)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder scaffolder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Sequence contains more than one matching element
PM> add-migration campaignsystemtype
Scaffolding migration 'campaignsystemtype'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.BuildCreateTableOperation(String entitySetName, String tableName, String schema, ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<FindAddedTables>b__31(XElement es)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder scaffolder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

PM>

Any help or guidance is much appreciated. I have a feeling from some google searchs that I will need to create a view on my MSSQL database to handle the relationship between the two.

Comment: Do you have errors elsewhere, LINQ? Possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202686/sequence-contains-more-than-one-matching-element, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021257/invalidoperationexception-sequence-contains-more-than-one-element, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256757/sequence-contains-more-than-one-element?rq=1

Comment: no other errors. I have had a look through all your suggestions and cant seem to get anywhere with it. Many comments point to it having a duplicate key field somewhere in the model. The system type table has around 10 units in it, I may just have to create a new Table in the MSSQL database and populate it from the other db on fly.. not ideal but I have stuck on this for two days now :(